# Symfony / api-platform PATCH NotEncodableValueException: "Syntax error"

Tags: php, api, symfony, api-platform.com

I use api-platform, GET and POST work's fine , i need to patch "isFinished" in my entity but i have an error :
REQUES Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Serializer\Exception\NotEncodableValueException: "Syntax error"

Do you think my entity have bad configuration ?
Thank you for help.

```
/**
 * @ApiResource()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=CurrentJourneyRepository::class)
 *
 * @ApiResource(
 *     collectionOperations={
 *          "get",
 *          "post"={"access_control"="is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY')"},
 *          "patch"
 *     },
 *     itemOperations={
 *          "get",
 *          "patch",
 *          "put",
 *          "delete"={"security"="is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN')"}
 *     },
 *     normalizationContext={"groups"={"journey:read"}},
 *     denormalizationContext={"groups"={"journey:write"}},
 *
 *
 * )
 * @ApiFilter(SearchFilter::class, properties={"user","isFinished","treasureWay"})
 */
class CurrentJourney
{
  /**
   * @ORM\Id
   * @ORM\GeneratedValue
   * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
   * @Groups({"journey:read"})
   */
  private $id;

  /**
   * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
   * @Groups({"journey:read", "journey:write"})
   */
  private $try;

  /**
   * //    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=User::class, inversedBy="currentJourneys")
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=User::class, inversedBy="waypoints")
   */
  private $user;

  /**
   * //    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Waypoint::class, inversedBy="currentJourneys")
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Waypoint::class, inversedBy="users")
   */
  private $waypoint;

  /**
   * @ORM\Column(type="integer",options={"default":"0"}) // integer: 0=abandonned ,1= in progress, 2= finished
   * @Groups({"journey:read", "journey:write"})
   */
  private $isFinished;

  /**
   * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
   */
  private $createdAt;

  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=TreasureWay::class, inversedBy="currentJourneys")
   */
  private $treasureWay;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is about your `Content-Type`, check it.
It should be `application/json` change it if it was somethings else